# When Amon faces Tarrlok, why wasn't Korra...? (S01E09)

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

In [TLOK S01E09](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Out_of_the_Past), Amon faces Tarrlok and re-kidnaps (transfer-kidnaps?) a kidnapped Korra. Amon tells lackeys to electrocute the box before opening the box. Well as it turns out...

[TLOK s1 spoiler]

> Amon is actually Noatak, Tarrlok's long longest older sibling who also bloodbends like Tarrlok and Yakone

So why didn't Amon just

[the same TLOK s1 spoiler]

> bloodbend Korra or something

either additionally or instead of having the box electrocuted? Maybe even just instead since electrocution would kill Korra (and I think for some reason Amon doesn't want Korra dead. I forgot already) ?

## Guess:

Ah Hell as I was typing this I think I already figured out the answer, but whatever I'll submit this anyway:

Amon can't quite do this without giving away the secret...?

[the same TLOK s1 spoiler]

> That e's a bloodbender

?

But well...ok 2 things here

1. Case 1: Amon doesn't want the lackeys to know the secret but doesn't care if Korra knows because . Soooo why not just close the door and handle Korra privately?
2. Case 2: Amon doesn't want Korra to know too. But what does it matter if Korra's gonna be under Amon's captivity?

Eh I guess it's just a big risk either way huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amon is overly-cautious. He refuses to use his bloodbending (except from taking away people's bending) in any instance other than life-threatening situations. To maintain this discipline is paramount to his success. He can make his bloodbending look like some Jesus power of anti-bending when he steals away their bending, though he can't make any other use of bloodbending look like anything other than bending. Any use will expose him to at least one person (the subject) and possibly others, including onlookers in the Equalist movement.

This is why he tells his Lieutenant to sedate her, and to be careful and certain that the job is accomplished correctly.

If he were to deal with her himself, his followers would get curious how he did it and why he wanted to do it alone instead of in front of others. And if she were to ever escape, she'd expose him as a hypocrite and liar. If others, like Tarrlok, could corroborate that that was true, then people would start to believe her.